# Chrome Canary removes Mapbox access token

Tags: google-chrome, mapbox-gl-js

since a few days I have problems developing a website with a mapbox map using Chrome Canary (Build: 68.0.3409.0) on macOS.

Problem:
Mapbox is sending requests with a query param `access_token=XXXX` this param gets a special treatment by Chrome Canary resulting in `access_token=anonymized`. Therefor mapbox is denying my request.
[Screenshot from DevTools Networktab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45qBY.png) [Screenshot from Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45yui.png)

Localy I can reproduces the problem easily and I also created a JS fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/LiquidSky/xr4rq9zw/) demonstrating the problem, however the offical mapbox examples work fine.

I have no adblocker or stuff installed, just the usual webdev tools.

Question:
Now I wonder if this is related to some security feature coming up in chrome or if this might even be a bug, for which I should open a bug ticket?

Thanks for every info :-D

Kind regards Nico

**SOLUTION:** Disable Ghostery

Answer (score 1):

Did you get anywhere with this? I have the exact same issue in stable chrome.
It only seems to have caused me issues in the past week or 2 though

Comment: Good timing :-D as I made a strange discovery today.
I installed Chrome Canary on my private MBP, to make further investigations and the problem did not appear.
Then I tackled it down to be the, for localhost, disabled AddBlocker "Ghostery". I didnt mention it in my original post because I made sure it was disabled and furthermore didnt show that it was blocking something. 
I also cant explain why the problem appeared in my jsfiddle example but not on the mapbox site itself.

Comment: Ah I have Ghostery also, so I'll try disabling that later today. Lets hope that is all it takes :)

Comment: Right on the money :), I've added an exclusion for Ghostery to localhost and my machine name (as I sometimes use that for various work bits) and now the maps load perfectly. I guess Ghostery recently updated which caused this, I didn't realise it affected 'local' domains so much though.

Comment: Glad I could help :-D

Comment: I have the same problem but disabling Ghostery or whitelisting the site doesn't help 